# Struts2 text tag doesn't select the right language property file

Tags: java, struts2

it's my first time with Struts2 tags. I have a class called `HomeAction` and two resources files, `HomeAction_en.properties` and `HomeAction_fr.properties`. I'm using Maven to build, and the resource files are at the proper location under `src/main/resources`; the property files end up at the same location as `HomeAction.class` after the build.

I use `<s:text name="..."/>` in `home.jsp`, but it picks up the message in the wrong property file. The action implements the `LocaleProvider` interface, and I traced the action in the debugger to make sure it has the proper locale. The default locale is `Locale.ENGLISH`, but `<s:text>` returns the messages from `HomeAction_fr.properties`.

I tried to replace `<s:text>` with `<s:property value="getText()"/>`. It does return the messages from the right property file, but then I hit another problem: the text from the property file is modified and ends up wrong in the browser. For example, the french property file contains this string: `Centre moteur &mdash; Requ&#xea;tes de Services`. It is rendered correctly with `<s:text>`, but it ends up as `Centre moteur &amp;mdash; Requ&amp;#xea;tes de Services` in the browser when using `<s:property>`, and it's not rendered properly.

I've been trying for a few hours to fix this without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since your name is D. Laroche and you're from Montréal, is it possible that it's retrieving the locale information from your browser?  The 'default' in question is applied if it can't determine the user's locale, but I'm guessing either your browser or machine itself has 'fr_ca' as the locale.

Comment: My understanding is that if the action implements the `LocaleProvider` interface (which defines method `getLocale()`), that should override the browser settings. Anyway I just tried in a browser configured with english as the preferred language and I still see the french version. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

Define Struts locale - struts.locale=en_US 
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
```